# Recode leaderboard?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a web page on which there is a leader board.
I need to know how I can align the script.
I need to align the names in their corresponding category, and the points in the points category.
They are currently together because it has the function of having more points go first and having less last.
The problem is that I also need to be able to align the other data, such as dates with the name & points.
This being the case that if the player falls from position, the points of HIS dates also go down.
Im making this with javascript because i need it to be sorted automatically just by changing the amount of total points.
Someone can help me?

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<h1>
Ameghino Poker
</h1>
<h2>
   2019
</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Jugadores</th>
    <th>Puntos</th>
    <th>6/9</th>
    <th>13/9</th>
    <th>20/9</th>
    <th>27/9</th>
    <th>4/10</th>
    <th>11/10</th>
    <th>18/10</th>
  </tr>
 <td> <td><div id="leaderboard" class="container">
    <!-- El script pega los score abajo de esto -->
    </div>
</td>
 </td>
</table>
    <button onclick="randomize()">Actualizar</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>


</html>
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:300,400,500');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  border-top: 4px solid #DC0000;
  background: #15151E;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  /* center the table horizontally */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

table {
  /* position relative to include a band on the left of the container */
  margin: 0rem 1rem;
  position: relative;
  /* cap the width of the table, allowing for a sizeable portion of white space if allowed by the viewport */
  width: calc(90vw - 2rem);
  max-width: 800px;
  /* spacing to separate the table rows vertically */
  border-spacing: 0 1rem;
}
/* with a pseudo element add a band with a repeating linear gradient */
table:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  right: calc(100% + 1rem);
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #38383F;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, #15151E 0px, #15151E 4px, #38383F 4px, #38383F 8px);
}
/* center every element nested in a table row */
table tr > * {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
/* align every second item of each row to the left */
table tr > *:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: left;
}


/* style the headings to have thin uppercase titles for the columns */
table th {
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.04rem;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  color: #eee;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* slightly increase the weight of the cell describing the position */
table td.position {
  font-weight: 500;
}

/* style the cell with the driver visually separating the first, last name and team */
table td.driver {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.05rem;
}
table td.driver strong {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
}
table td.driver span {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin-left: 0.75rem;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: #999;
  letter-spacing: initial;
}

/* style the span nested in the last cell to have the gap in a rounded rectangle */
table td.gap span {
  background: #38383F;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* on smaller viewports remove the third column from sight */
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  table tr > *:nth-child(3) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```
let scores = [
    {name: "Player6", score: 6800},
    {name: "Player3", score: 6050},
    {name: "Player1", score: 5300},
    {name: "Player2", score: 4750},
    {name: "Player5", score: 4150},
    {name: "Player4", score: 3000},
    ];


function updateLeaderboardView() {
    let leaderboard = document.getElementById("leaderboard");
    leaderboard.innerHTML = "";

    scores.sort(function(a, b){ return b.score - a.score  });
    let elements = []; // Elementos para actualizar colores
    // Elementos para cada jugador
    for(let i=0; i<scores.length; i++) {
        let name = document.createElement("div");
        let score = document.createElement("div");
        name.classList.add("name");
        score.classList.add("score");
        name.innerText = scores[i].name;
        score.innerText = scores[i].score;

        let scoreRow = document.createElement("div");
        scoreRow.classList.add("row");
        scoreRow.appendChild(name);
        scoreRow.appendChild(score);
        leaderboard.appendChild(scoreRow);

        elements.push(scoreRow);

    }

    let colors = ["gold", "silver", "#cd7f32"];
    for(let i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        elements[i].style.color = colors[i];
    }
}
updateLeaderboardView();
function randomize() {
    for(var i=0; i<scores.length; i++) {
        scores[i].score = Math.floor(Math.random() * (600 - 300 + 1)) + 300;
    }
    // when your data changes, call updateLeaderboardView
    updateLeaderboardView();
}
```

Actually the name appear with the points too.
I need the names below "Jugadores" (players)
and the points below "Puntos" (The total points).
And i need add 7 categories more with more points (the parts of the total points).
If possible, I need to know how to make the points of each date add up to the total without having to calculate the total me. Make it automatic. As a calculator but in leaderboard and that is aligned with the player online, not below it.

Comment: 'Actually the name appear with the points too.' ==> did you only just work out what your own code does? Also 'I need to know how I can align the script' ==> What do you mean by this?

Comment: So in the above snippet, what code did you write? Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. Please include your attempt to sort the object in the question too.